# Dereference the variable and append it with other string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

What I want to do is to **read one line from a text file and append .in** at the end of every line.

Here is my code.

```
while read line; do
echo "${line}".in
done < sets.txt
```

sets.txt's contents are:

```
set1
set2
set3
```

Thus this code supposed to print

```
set1.in
set2.in
set3.in
```

However this code produce

```
.in
.in
.in
```

Can you help me to solve this problem?
Thanks! :)

Comment: Works fine here; what version of bash do you have?

Comment: your codes worked here.. it gave expected output. do you have other codes in your `while...do` block?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Kent/ No. That's all I got in the script

Comment: Try `echo "$line.in"`

Comment: could your `sets.txt` have been created on a Windows machine and now you're processing on a linux machine? In any case you really have very little to loose (assuming you have a safe copy of `sets.txt`) by running `dos2unix sets.txt` and see if that clears up your problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me. (and it looks like it works for others too). Hard to say what's the problem from here. However, an alternative might be to use `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s.in\n", $0}' input_file > output_file
```

(Don't use the the same file for input and output! this would truncate the input file)

Comment: (yeah, I see this now.. was too fast ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about trying `cat sets.txt | while read line`? That's more standard.

Comment: It's less standard, and less desirable.